# Django heatmap d3.js passing returned data from search

Tags: django, postgresql, d3.js, search, repository

am creating a searchable repository that displays heatmap after the search is completed in django (windows) and postgresql.
my code for the search is not used to HTML.

views.py

```
def search_result(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ChemSearched = request.POST.get('ChemSearched')
        tarname = Bindll.objects.filter(targetnameassignedbycuratorordatasource__contains=ChemSearched)[:10]

        return render(request, 'Search/search_result.html',
            {'ChemSearched':ChemSearched,'tarname':tarname})
    else:
        return render(request, 'Search/search_result.html',{})
```

Searchresults.html

```
...

                <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <strong><h1>{% if ChemSearched %}
            <script>


            var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30},
              width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
              height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


            var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
            .append("svg")
              .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
              .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
              .attr("transform",
                    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
             {% for Bindll in tarname %}


                var myGroups = [  "{{ Bindll }}"  ]
                var myVars = [  "{{ Bindll.ki_nm }}"  ]
             {% endfor %}
               


            var x = d3.scaleBand()
              .range([ 0, width ])
              .domain(myGroups)
              .padding(0.01);
            svg.append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
              .call(d3.axisBottom(x))


            var y = d3.scaleBand()
              .range([ height, 0 ])
              .domain(myVars)
              .padding(0.01);
            svg.append("g")
              .call(d3.axisLeft(y));


            var myColor = d3.scaleLinear()
              .range(["white", "#69b3a2"])
              .domain([1,100])


            d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/heatmap_data.csv", function(data) {

              svg.selectAll()
                  .data(data, function(d) {return d.group+':'+d.variable;})
                  .enter()
                  .append("rect")
                  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group) })
                  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.variable) })
                  .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
                  .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
                  .style("fill", function(d) { return myColor(d.value)} )

            })

        </script>                   
                        <br>
                        {% for Bindll in tarname %}
                            {{ Bindll }}--{{ Bindll.ki_nm }}-{{ Bindll.ic50_nm }} - {{ Bindll.kd_nm  }} - {{ Bindll.ec50_nm }} - <br>

                        {% endfor %}

                    {% else %}
                                <strong>No Entry</strong>
                        
                {% endif %}
```

never used webs before so any help why the chart is only showing one element, tried using for loop to append the values in a list did not work
but its printing quite fine the results, any way you can guide me on what am doing wrong, to make the heatmap show my results.
Thanks

Comment: It would greatly help if you could create a [mre] of the HTML generated by your code with some sample data, preferably in a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you build your scale domains this way instead, and see if it works.  I don't see the immediate problem outside of a possible mistake in the domains:

```
var myGroups= data.map(d=>d.group).filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i),
    myVars = data.map(d=>d.variable).filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i);
```